# Changing an objects color while it is dragged

Tags: java, swing, colors, drag-and-drop

I am trying to get a circle which starts of as black to change color to red while it is dragged. I have been told I need to change the Circle so it has a Color attribute as well as a position, and change the update method so it changes that  Color as well as the position.
But I don't know how to do this. 
Any help would be appricated, thank you.

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Circle  extends JPanel{
    private double x;
    private double y;
    private double r;
    Color color;
    Graphics g;
    private Color Circle;



    public Circle(double x, double y, double r, Color color) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.r = r;

        this.color = color;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {



        g.setColor(Color.red);


        g.fillOval((int)Math.round(x-r),(int)Math.round(y-r),
            (int)Math.round(2.0*r),(int)Math.round(2.0*r));




    }



    public double distanceTo(double x, double y) {
        return (Math.abs(this.x-x) + Math.abs(this.y-y));
    }

    public void update(double x, double y)  {
         this.x = x;
         this.y = y;










    }





    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
g.setColor(Color.red);
```

Don't hard code the Color you use to paint the circle. Instead your class could have methods like setColor(...) and getColor(...). Then the painting code would use:

```
g.setColor(getColor());
```

Now in the mousePressed() method of your MouseListner you can use:

```
setColor( getDraggingColor );
```

and in mouseReleased you can use:

```
setColor( getForeground() );
```

So you would need to store the dragging color when you create the class.

Also, since you are doing custom painting on a component you should be overriding the paintComponent() method of the panel to paint the circle. Creating a draw(...) method does do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You need to repaint the component to take the effect.

Call this method after updating the color.

```
this.repaint();
```

Comment: You already have an `update`method, pass new a color parameter with the `x` and `y`, or create a new method `updateColor(Color c)`